# Error "Specified cast is not valid" when pulling from spreadsheet in C#

Tags: c#, excel, import

I have a C# program that is supposed to pull data from a small, four-column spreadsheet (.xlsx). It reads the first column fine, however when it gets to the second I get the following error:

"Specified cast is not valid"

I've checked and re-checked the format of the cells, and there is no difference between the first column, which reads just fine, and the second. Below are the values for the first row in the spreadsheet. Each value represents one separate column.

> 121220 330004  Dual    02/22/2012

And here is the code that I am using. the Id variable loads just fine, it is the courseCode which is causing the problem.

```
string connectionString = @"Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;"
    + "Data Source=C:\Projects\sym_AgentServices_INT\Book1.xlsx;"
    + "Extended Properties='Excel 8.0;HDR=Yes;IMEX=1'";
string queryString = "SELECT * FROM [CE$]";

try
{
    OleDbDataReader reader;
    using (OleDbConnection connection = new OleDbConnection(connectionString))
    {
        OleDbCommand command = new OleDbCommand(queryString, connection);
        connection.Open();
        reader = command.ExecuteReader();

        while (reader.Read())
        {
            string Id = "";
            string courseCode = "";
            string partner = "";
            string effectiveDate = "";
            string expirationDate = "";

            Id = reader.GetString(0);
            courseCode = reader.GetString(1);
            partner = reader.GetString(2);
            effectiveDate = reader.GetString(3);
            expirationDate = reader.GetString(4);
        }
    }
}
```

EDIT

I've analyzed the reader object at runtime and found the following: by expanding base a number of times and opening up the _bindings property of System.Data.OleDb.OleDbDataReader I found that there was only one entry in there ("0"). However, if I open 0 up, then expand the _columnBindings property I find the values 0 - 4.

Could my syntax be incorrect when extracting data from the reader ("reader.GetString(x)")?

FINAL EDIT

Instead of using .GetString(x) I would highly recommend simply using reader[x].ToString(). This solved the problem.

Comment: what is the actual value of courseCode also is courseCode in the xcel spreadsheet defined as Int , Text, ...ect

Comment: It's defined as "general", same as the first column. The value I have listed in the spreadsheet is that actual value of courseCode. There aren't any computations done to get that number.

Comment: Sorry, by actual value did you mean the value in the reader object?

Comment: @Brett: Tried that already and I still get the same error.

Comment: Check for dbnull?  reader[1] != DbNull ? readerGetString(1) : null;  Just guessing...will but out hereafter...

Comment: initiated "flag" boolean variable to false, then ran this line of code: "if (reader[1] == null) { flag = true; }" after which flag was still false..

Comment: I don't think comparing for null is the right approach.  See:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.dbnull.aspx

Comment: I see, thx. I adjusted the code like so: "if (DBNull.Value.Equals(reader[1])){flag = true;}" and still got the same result.

Comment: Are all the IDs in the first column numeric?  Are all the course codes in the second column numeric?

Comment: @NealR The solution to your problem might become apparent if you examine the run-time type of `reader[0]` and `reader[1]`.

Comment: Are you sure this is happening on column 1?  I would try changing every statement to `<variable> = reader[x] == DBNull.Value ? reader[x].ToString() : string.Empty;`

Comment: I can see the values as being accurate for both [0] and [1]...

Comment: I did see something while analyzing the reader object at runtime, please refer to my edit above

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When I use reader[n].ToString(), the error goes away for me:

```
        string connectionString = @"Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0; Data Source=d:\temp\Book1.xlsx; Extended Properties='Excel 8.0;HDR=Yes;IMEX=1'";
        string queryString = "SELECT * FROM [CE$]";

        OleDbDataReader reader;
        using (OleDbConnection connection = new OleDbConnection(connectionString))
        {
            OleDbCommand command = new OleDbCommand(queryString, connection);
            connection.Open();

            DataSet ds = new DataSet("Book1");

            IDataAdapter adapter = new OleDbDataAdapter(queryString, connection);
            adapter.Fill(ds);

            reader = command.ExecuteReader();

            while (reader.Read())
            {
                string Id = "";
                string courseCode = "";
                string partner = "";
                string effectiveDate = "";
                string expirationDate = "";

                Id = reader[0].ToString();
                courseCode = reader[1].ToString();
                partner = reader[2].ToString();
                effectiveDate = reader[3].ToString();
                expirationDate = reader[4].ToString();

                //Id = reader.GetString(0);
                //courseCode = reader.GetString(1);
                //partner = reader.GetString(2);
                //effectiveDate = reader.GetString(3);
                //expirationDate = reader.GetString(4);
            }
        }
```

Here's my test data set...

```
ID  Course Code     Partner Effective Date Expiration Date
100 5               MS      10/3/2012       10/3/2013
200 21-400          Oracle  10/3/2012       10/3/2013
300                 Goog    10/3/2012       10/3/2013
```

Comment: This worked. I have another program where I used the reader.GetString() method, but I guess it wasn't right for this one. Thanks